Zoom effect on hovering image, bring details of image
Why my handleMouseMove function is not working properly? I am trying to add zoom on hovering of image. It seems calculation is wrong, I need help how it is working, how to write it correctly.  Trying to get the same effect as in amazon when you hover product , it show you little bit closer product. In my case it doesnt works. Please help, thank you
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Index = () => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState('/img.jpg');

  const handleImageClick = (src) => {
    setHero(src);
    const magnifier = document.getElementById('magnifier');
    magnifier.style.backgroundImage = `url(${src})`;
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const magnifier = document.getElementById('magnifier');
    const detailImage = document.getElementById('detailImage');
    const rect = detailImage.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    const offsetX = magnifier.offsetWidth / 2;
    const offsetY = magnifier.offsetHeight / 2;

    magnifier.style.backgroundPosition = `-${(x * 2) - offsetX}px -${(y * 2) - offsetY}px`;
    magnifier.style.left = `${x - offsetX}px`;
    magnifier.style.top = `${y - offsetY}px`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      
          <div className="col-11 col-md-4 bg-light border p-3 rounded-3">
            <div className="zoom-container">
              <div
                id="detailImage"
                className="detail-image"
                onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}

                onMouseLeave={() => {
                  const magnifier = document.getElementById('magnifier');
                  magnifier.style.display = 'none';
                }}

                onMouseEnter={() => {
                  const magnifier = document.getElementById('magnifier');
                  magnifier.style.display = 'block';
                }}
              >
                <img
                  id="mainImage"
                  src={hero}
                  className="border zoom-image"
                  alt="card"
                />
                <div id="magnifier" className="magnifier"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
              <img
                src="/img.jpg"
                className="border"
                style={{ position: 'relative', width: '31%' }}
                alt="card1"
                onClick={() => handleImageClick('/img.jpg')}
              />
              <img
                src="/img.jpg"
                className="border"
                style={{ position: 'relative', width: '31%' }}
                alt="card2"
                onClick={() => handleImageClick('/img1.jpg')}
              />
              <img
                src="/img.jpg"
                className="border"
                style={{ position: 'relative', width: '31%' }}
                alt="card3"
                onClick={() => handleImageClick('/img2.jpg')}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          
      </div>

      <style>{`
        .zoom-container {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .detail-image {
          position: relative;
        }

        .zoom-image {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .magnifier {
          position: absolute;
          border: 3px solid #000;
          border-radius: 50%;
          cursor: none;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          display: none;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 200%;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;



First, I multiply the actual image width by a scaler to get the zoomed image width. Then, its position must be scaler times the negative of the mouse coordinates plus half the size of the magnifier circle. This plus is important because it moves the top left corner of our zoomed image to the center.
I also check a few conditions to overcome a kind of overflow problem. With this block, the magnifying circle will always be inside the container unless it is very large. If you want your mouse to be in the middle of the magnifying circle, remove this block and use overflow: hidden on zoom-container as below.
const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const magnifier = document.getElementById('magnifier');
    const detailImage = document.getElementById('detailImage');
    const rect = detailImage.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    const offsetX = magnifier.offsetWidth / 2;
    const offsetY = magnifier.offsetHeight / 2;

    magnifier.style.left = `${x - offsetX}px`;
    magnifier.style.top = `${y - offsetY}px`;

    const scaler = 3;

    magnifier.style.backgroundSize = `${rect.width * scaler}px`;
    magnifier.style.backgroundPositionX = `${-1 * scaler * x + offsetX}px`;
    magnifier.style.backgroundPositionY = `${-1 * scaler * y + offsetY}px`;

    const positionX = x < offsetX * 2 || rect.width - x >= offsetX * 2 ? 1 : -1;
    const positionY = y < offsetY * 2 || rect.height - y >= offsetY * 2 ? 1 : -1;
    magnifier.style.translate = `${50 * positionX}% ${50 * positionY}%`;
    
    magnifier.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};


Finally, I recommend you not to hide cursor but show it like this.
.zoom-container {
    ...
    cursor: crosshair;
    /* overflow: hidden; */ 
}
.magnifier {
    ...
    /* cursor: none; */
}

Demo

Change backgroundPosition calculation to:
magnifier.style.backgroundPosition = `-${((x / detailImage.offsetWidth) * 100)}% -${((y / detailImage.offsetHeight) * 100)}%`;

